# To prove $\int_{a}^{\theta} f(t)dt = \theta f(\theta)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Given a real continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(t)dt = 0$ where $a \gt 0$. Prove that $\exists$ $\theta$ where $a<\theta<b$ such that $\int_{a}^{\theta} f(t)dt = \theta f(\theta)$.

My attempts

Consider the function $G(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(x)dx - xf(x)$. I wanted to prove that G attains both positive and negative values so as to use intermediate value theorem to prove the existence of a zero($\theta$). But I could not.
What I could obtain were

1. G(a)G(b) = af(a)bf(b).
2. If f is not the zero function (in which case we are done), $\exists$ $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ and $f(y_0)$ are +ve and -ve due to continuity of f. Thus a zero of f is also known to exist due to continuity of f. Couldn't utilise this further.

Other methods of attempt

Consider $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$. By Fundamental theorem of integral calculus, F is differentiable on (a,b) and thus by applying Mean Value theorem, I have $\frac{\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt}{x-a} = \frac{F(x) - F(a)}{x-a)}$ = f(c) for some $c \in (a,x)$. This only concludes $\int_{a}^{\theta} f(t)dt$ = $f(c)(\theta-a)$.

Consider the differentiable function $H(x) = x\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$, on [a,b]. H(a) = H(b) = 0. Thus, by Rolle's theorem, $\exists$ $\theta \in (a,b)$ such that $H^{\prime}(\theta)$ = $\theta$ f($\theta$) + $\int_{a}^{\theta} f(t)dt$ = 0. Thus, I got something like $\exists$ $\theta$ such that $\int_{a}^{\theta} f(t)dt = - \theta f(\theta)$. Totally not getting the expected answer!!! Any help??

Comment: Since $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = 0$, unless $f\equiv 0$, it must attain positive as well as negative values. In either case, there is a $c \in (a,b)$ with $f(c) = 0$. If also $\int_a^c f(x)\,dx = 0$, you're done. Otherwise, you could search from $c$ on to find the necessary points where $G$ takes on different signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What happens if you apply Rolle's theorem to $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$?