# Prove that there exists a $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that $\int_a^\xi f(x)dx=f(\xi)\xi.$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $a>0$, and $\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$.

Prove that there exists a $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that $$\int_a^\xi f(x)dx=f(\xi)\xi.$$

Thanks ahead!!!

Comment: Hi Paul, this looks like a homework question. Generally, it is expected of people to provide their attempt at the problem and to ask questions specifically pertaining to their work rather than asking for complete solutions. Do you mind sharing your progress?

Comment: Maybe rearrange the formula as in ${1 \over \xi} \int_a^\xi f(x) dx = f(\xi)$?

Comment: A [search with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_a%5E%5Cxi%20f(x)dx%3Df(%5Cxi)%5Cxi.%24&p=1) shows that this has been asked and answered before, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518944/42969.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_a^x f(s)ds$. Notice since $a >0$ $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and since $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ we have $\int_a^x f(s)ds$ continuous in $[a,b]$. So $g$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and $g(a)=g(b)=0$. Apply rolle's theorem to find some $c \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
0=g'(c)=-\frac{1}{c^2}\int_a^c f(s)ds + \frac{1}{c}f(c).
$$
Then you have
$$
\int_a^c f(s)ds=f(c)c
$$
for some $c \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt-xf(x)$. If $f(a)=0$ or $f(b)=0$, $g(a)=0$ or $g(b)=0$.

Suppose that $f(a)\neq 0$ and $f(b)\neq 0$.

If $f(a)f(b)<0$, $g(a)g(b)<0 $ there exists $c$ such that $g(c)=0$

Suppose $f(a)>0, f(b)>0$. $f^{-1}(0)$ is a closed subset of $[a,b]$. It is not empty, otherwise $f(x)\geq 0$ for every $x\in [a,b]$ and $\int_a^bf(t)dt>0$. Let $u=min(x\in [a,b], f(u)=0$. If $x< u, f(x)\geq 0$. We deduce that $g(u)=\int_a^uf(t)dt>0$.
$g(a)=-f(a)a<0$ implies there exists $c\in [a,u]$ with $g(c)=0$.

If $f(a)<0, f(b)<0$ uses a similar argument.

Comment: Thanks very much